# Unable to use Fabric-js in Svelte

Tags: svelte

I am working on an app requiring Fabric-js in Svelte. My code is:

```
<script>
  import fabric from "fabric";

  let canv = new fabric.Canvas("c");

  const rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 10,
    top: 10,
    width: 20,
    height: 15,
    fill: "blue"
  });
  canv.add(rect);
</script>
  <canvas id="c" width="500" height="300" />
```

but I get an error at the console `TypeError: fabric_1.Canvas is not a constructor`. If I however  query the fabric object in the console, everything seems fine. Wondering what could be the problem.

Answer (score 11):

You need to do `import { fabric } from 'fabric'` — if you look closely at the object you imported, you'll see that it has a single property named `fabric`.

By the time `new fabric.Canvas("c")` runs, your canvas element hasn't been created yet. So you need to put it in an `onMount` lifecycle callback:

```html
<script>
  import { fabric } from "fabric";
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  let canvas;

  onMount(() => {
    let canv = new fabric.Canvas(canvas);

    const rect = new fabric.Rect({
      left: 10,
      top: 10,
      width: 20,
      height: 15,
      fill: "blue"
    });
    canv.add(rect);
  });
</script>

<canvas bind:this={canvas} width="500" height="300" />
```

Notice also that I'm using `bind:this={canvas}` to assign the DOM element to a local variable, and using that instead of an ID. This is more robust, as it allows you to have multiple instances of the component without the IDs clobbering each other.

Comment: This helped me a lot

Comment: i prefer `npm i -D fabric-pure-browser` without node-canvas / jsdom dependency